Upgrading to maximum capacity ECC RAM on AMD Ryzen
I would like to upgrade my system to ECC RAM.
My system is: Ryzen 9 5950X, X570 Phantom Gaming-ITX/TB3
Board and CPU supports ECC Unregistered/Unbuffered.
First question
I found some modules but only 32GB. Is there some 64GB modules on market? I have only two slots. (Yes I know that my board may be supports only 64GB, may be not...)
Because
~# dmidecode -t memory
...
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        ....
        Maximum Capacity: 128 GB
        ....

Second question
I found these two modules

M378A4G43MB1-CTD
M378A4G43AB2-CWE

B1 is slower than B2, but B1 but costs double so much. It seems I don't understand something or why B2 is so cheap? What is the main difference between this modules.
B1 https://www.senetic.de/product/M378A4G43MB1-CTD
B2 https://www.senetic.de/product/M378A4G43AB2-CWE
2x Difference
I hope it's alowed to post links to shops...

M378A4G43MB1-CTD
M378A4G43AB2-CWE Seems not to be an ECC RAM.

Unregistered ECC DDR4 UDIMMs max out at 32GB
While the maximum DIMM size for DDR4 is 64 GB, the largest DDR4 chips (the individual guys that go on a module) currently max out at 32 Gb/4 GB. This is a technical limitation, not a limitation of the DDR4 specification. Thus, to put 64 GB on a single module/stick, you need at least 16 memory chips (more if you want ECC). The more chips you add, the greater the strain on the memory controller. Registered memory decreases the load on the memory controller, which is why it's often used for high-capacity modules. As such, the largest unregistered DIMMs currently available max out at 32 GB, using 8x4GB memory chips. Given that DDR5 has been released and is being used by the latest AMD and Intel chips, I would not expect this to change, as there is little incentive for DRAM manufacturers to create higher-capacity DDR4 memory chips.
I would recommend this 2x32GB DDR4-3200 MHz kit or equivalent - $158
Ryzen does benefit from faster and lower-latency RAM. However, with ECC DIMMs, you're going to be stuck at the officially supported JDEC speeds, which max out at DDR4-3200 (PC4-25600) and a CAS latency of 12.5-15ns depending on timings. You can't generally overclock ECC RAM, and it certainly won't come with out-of-the-box overclocking support (EXPO/XMP.) As such, I'd recommend just getting the fastest 2x32GB kit you can find, and not worrying about the timings too much.
For ECC RAM in particular, used prices tend to be much cheaper, since they're often stripped out of retired workstations/servers and resold on the cheap.
Without knowing where you're getting your pricing from on those Samsung modules, it'd difficult to tell exactly why one is more expensive. I would suspect this is due to limited supply, but it could also be down to other minor differences.

Thanks for this explanation. I get my prices here
B1 https://www.senetic.de/product/M378A4G43MB1-CTD
B2 https://www.senetic.de/product/M378A4G43AB2-CWE
The dirrerence is 2x.

answer to question 1
yes there are but they are costly
Micron 64GB DDR4-3200 RDIMM 2Rx4 CL22 example can be purchase from mircon site for about $231.80
answer to question 2
b1 MT is 3200 while b2 is MT is 2666
so that is one main reason but also the chip design M378A4G43MB1-CTD is design for heavier workloads

B1 - is 2666 and B2 - is DDR4-3200, whats why i'm wondering.
https://semiconductor.samsung.com/emea/dram/module/udimm/m378a4g43mb1-ctd/
https://semiconductor.samsung.com/emea/dram/module/udimm/m378a4g43ab2-cwe/
I check on Micron site but not found any UDIMM 32GB above. Here link https://www.micron.com/products/memory/dram-modules/udimm
